# SED replace version with link, but got unterminated substitute in regular expression

Tags: sed

Trying to replace the current line in a json file from

```
"our-package": "2.0.0",
```

to

```
"our-package": "https://website.com/",
```

I have tried:

```
website="https://website.com/"
sed -i '' "s|our-package[\"]: [\"]2.0.0|our-package[\"]: '$website'" FILE
```

but got unterminated substitute in regular expression error. Please advice

Preferred a solution with sed since we aren't using jq.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts, keep it up, Could you please do let us know if this is a json file?

Comment: yes it is json file!

Comment: Then kindly do update your json file samples in your question in text form and let us know then. Also can you use tools like `jq` who know how to deal with json?